# Tablesorter : filter_functions and sort by value

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, tablesorter

I'm using latest version (2.28.8) of tablesorter with filter widget and would like to :

1. sort by percentage list by ASC/DESC order
2. define a custom filter to list some predefined range
3. order my custom filter to be ascending one (<5% then 10%-20%,...)

I'm definining a  like this : `<td data-text="5-10%">10</td>` to have range filters.

Here is a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dntay90v/12/):

- Min Column has numbers defined in data-text to define the order
- Max column doesn't have.

=> Can we do this more properly? (goal #3 of list above)

**Observed** : The filter works fine. But the click ASC/DESC is wrong. Note that the descending order is correct for Max column but not the ascending order.

**Expected** : How can I achive my 3 goals?

I saw [this example](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter-custom.html) but as I have plenty table with this plugin, I should fine a way to apply the filter_functions for a single table having already the tablesorter initialized.

Tablesorter is called :

```
$(".tablesorter-scroll").tablesorter({
    widthFixed : false,
    showProcessing: true,

    widgets: ['filter', 'columnSelector', 'scroller'],
    ...
});
```

Hope I was clear enough, don't hesitate to ask.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [`filter_functions` demo](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter-custom.html). You can define a set of filter functions to apply to the select. Additionally, you can add a class to the header to target instead of define a function for each column:

HTML

```
<table id="task">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class='ranges filter-onlyAvail'>Min [%]</th>
      <th class='ranges filter-onlyAvail'>Max [%]</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>5 %</td>
      <td>10 %</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>50 %</td>
      <td>100 %</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>0 %</td>
      <td>4 %</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>10 %</td>
      <td>15 %</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>25 %</td>
      <td>50 %</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Script

```
$(function() {
  $("#task").tablesorter({
    widgets: ["zebra", "filter"],
    widgetOptions: {
      filter_functions: {
        '.ranges' : {
          '<= 5%': function(e, n) { return n <= 5; },
          '10% - 20%': function(e, n) { return n >= 10 && n <= 20; },
          '20% - 50%': function(e, n) { return n >= 20 && n <= 50; },
          '>= 50%': function(e, n) { return n >= 50; }
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Wow ! I love it !! Very clever solution. Simple and answer all my 3 problems. Thanks a lot Mottie, I really appreciate your plugin and your very fast answers.

Comment: P.S: To anyone coming to this post, I forgot to mention there is a typo error on the JS: there is an extra comma here after the number parameter  `'<= 5%': function(e, n,)`

Comment: Thanks, I've removed the extra comma! And you're welcome! :D